# Iterating over keys in dictionary, which are tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

Assuming I have a dictionary whose keys are tuples. Is it possible to to iterate over the keys of the dictionary and only return the keys which are have a certain value in the first position of their tuple? For example:

```
my_dict = {('a','a'):'b', ('a','b'):'b', ('b','a'):'a'}
def function(given):
    for (given,x) in my_dict:
        print((given,x))

function('a')
```

I want the function to print the following:

```
>> ('a','a')
>> ('a','b')
```

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: So, what's the issue you are having, exactly?

Comment: I have given a value. I want to print all tuples in the dictionary, that have the given value as their first element

Comment: ... Yes. You seem to understand how to iterate over the keys, so what *exactly* is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the first value is the `given` key with an `if` statement before printing. Also, you should not use `given` for your loop variable, otherwise you overshadow you function argument.

```
def function(given):
    for k in my_dict:
        if given == k[0]:
            print(k)
```

Comment: I already came up with this solution, I just thought there might be an easier way to do this...

Comment: There are slightly convoluted ways using `map`, `filter` or list comprehension, but this is the most straightforward and prefered way to do. Why would you want to avoid an `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(given):
    for (key,value) in my_dict:
        if(key==given):
            print((key,value))
```